# Virtual .git archive with license key for node modules

Tags: node.js, git, npm

Not really sure how to title this, but here is what i want to do.
I have some private node modules that i want to offer using license keys.

So the installation of the node modules should looks something like:

```
npm install http://example.com/example.git?key=12123123
```

I don't want the example.git to be an actual .git instance. If they key is valid i want to be able to get the proper archive for node. I can handle the key verification using php but not really sure what the output form should be.

Thanks,
Radu

Answer (score 0):

Actually archiving the git repository as gz tarball allows me to install it using npm install so i have

npm install http://example.com/repo.php?key=123123123

Inside repo.php i have

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
readfile($f_location);
```